# How to get full path from savefiledialog and use in "startInfo.Arguments"?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my case the `SaveFileDialog` will not write any file, but I want to use to specify the path for a command line app which will create the logfile on the same location as "saved" in the sf dialog.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "*.txt";
string sfdname = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName);
}

startInfo.Arguments = "--log=" + Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `Path.GetFileName`:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "--log=\"" + sfd.FileName + "\"";
```

Comment: With this I get the full path of the file (I checked with a textbox) but the command line app don't recognize it.

Comment: @user830054: Try adding quotes around the path. See updated answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
Path.GetFullPath(sfd.FileName);
```

Instead of

```
Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName);
```

Complete version...

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "*.txt";
string sfdname = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  Path.GetFullPath(sfd.FileName);
}

startInfo.Arguments = "--log=" + Path.GetFullPath(sfd.FileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong dialog form based on what you are describing.

Try using the `FolderBrowserDialog` class:

```
string folderPath = string.Empty;

using (FolderBrowserDialog fdb = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
  if (fdb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ){
    folderPath = fdb.SelectedPath;
  }
}

if (folderPath != string.Empty) {
  startInfo.Arguments = "--log=" + folderPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files | *.jpg";
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                 employee_dp.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                 string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                 string onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                 filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                 filepath = filepath + "\\\\" + onlyFileName;
                 MessageBox.Show(filepath);
```

Comment: What is that `*`?

Comment: typo sorry hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) would help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be using the wrong `FileSaveDialog`.
The one in `Win32.dll` doesn't provide the full path, but the one in `System.Windows.Forms` does.